# what does "var self = module.exports;" mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw a line of code:

```
var self = module.exports ;
```

in a nodejs project.

I know the meaning of "module.exports", and I cannot find any information about this code. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time people use a variable called `self` to store a reference to something that might be overwritten in another function context. (it could be called anything: `_this`, `that`, etc.)

Example:

```
    var lib = require('lib');

    var self = module.exports;        

    function exportModule(module) {
        // note that 'module' now refers to this function's argument
        // but that's ok because I stored 'module.exports' in 'self' earlier
        for(var p in module) {
           self[p] = module[p];
        }
    }        

    exportModule(lib);
```

Important Note:

`self` is probably a bad variable name for this. In practice, `self` is often used to store the `this` of a function (which is needed because `this` is automatically overwritten in a new function scope). The variable name `self` is purely a convention, but breaking the convention might be confusing for other developers.

A better variable name might be `_exports`.

In the end, you probably shouldn't name a variable `module` or `exports` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is just someone saving a shortcut for `module.exports` into a local variable so references can be made to `self.something` rather than `module.exports.something`.  It could just as well be:

```
var myModule = module.exports;
```

The name `self` has no special meaning in the language - just a variable name - though it is often used as a saved value of `this` in closures (which is not what it's being used for here).

This extra shortcut is generally not needed because `exports` is already a predefined shortcut for `module.exports` so the use of the variable named `self` must just be a personal preference coding style or is being used by someone who did not realize that `exports` is already a predefined shortcut.